# JavaScript Es6 Class 'extends' looses abstract class methods

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, extends

I am new to ES6 and am refactoring code to use inheritance but have come across this error that I do not understand.

Please can someone help explain this, the child class cannot access the parent class's methods when added to an array:

```
class abstract1 {
    constructor(){
    }

    method1_2(){
        console.log('method1_2');
    }

    method1_1(){
        console.log('method1_1');
        this.method1_2();
    }
}

class test extends abstract1{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    method2_1(){
        console.log('method2_1');
        this.method1_1();
    }
}
let tmp = new test();
tmp.method2_1();

//All good with world, result:
// method2_1
// method1_1
// method1_2

console.log('Now Run from a callback');
let eventActions = [];
eventActions.push({test:tmp.method2_1});
eventActions[0].test();

//Not good with world:
// method2_1
// Uncaught TypeError: this.method1_1 is not a function
//    at Object.method2_1 [as test] (<anonymous>:22:8)
//    at <anonymous>:35:17
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6, classes, or inheritance. A method that is added to an array in the way you did cannot even access "own" methods. Try `console.log(this)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a call to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
eventActions.push({test:tmp.method2_1.bind(tmp)});
```